# "Merging is blocked. The base branch restricts merging to authorized users.", but the user seems to have permission

Tags: github, merge, permissions, pull-request

[image: Merging is blocked. The base branch restricts merging to authorized users.]

"Merging is blocked. The base branch restricts merging to authorized users.", but after reviewing all of the Branch settings and Rules, the user seems to have permission.

What gives?

*There will probably be many answers to this question, since the error message can have many meanings. (I was not able to find a clear question asking this, so hopefully this can serve as a growing repository of all of the solutions that people have for this scenario.)*

Answer (score 5):

In my case, there was a lack of clarity on the meanings of certain branch permissions.

We have this option selected:

> Restrict who can push to matching branches

This would seem to be referring to Pushes only, but after a bit of research into the Github docs it became clear that this permission actually prevents Pull Requests as well if this other permission is set:

> Require a pull request before merging

In the docs it says:

> People, teams, and apps that have permission to push to a protected branch will still need to create a pull request when pull requests are required.

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#restrict-who-can-push-to-matching-branches